# use OpenCV video in apps

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I wish to create a program which gets two inputs from two different webcams. I then wish to use one of these videos as output so that e.g. google meet or zoom will be able to show them. Then if i press s it should switch between these videos. This part I can do myself.

What I need is a command 'switch' which should switch between the videos.

I am finding no way that one of these applications can get these videos.

I am using Python 3.7 (anaconda)

Here is my code (i got it from https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html, also note that i used four spaces because I am not very familiar with asking questions on StackOverflow):

```
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
cap2 = cv.VideoCapture(1)


while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    ret2, frame2 = cap2.read()
    # if frame is read correctly ret is True
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    if not ret2:
        print("Can't receive frame2 (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break


    # Display the resulting frame
    cv.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv.imshow('frame2', frame2)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        print("Exiting...")
        break


cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Comment: you mean cv.imshow should show just the desired frame ?

Comment: No not like that. I actually mean that the video should be used by e.g. zoom instead of showing it on the screen with cv.imshow. But e.g. zoom should only use the desired video.

Comment: I know in discord or team you coul simply select the window you want to share. Sorry can't help with zoom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i accidentally found a solution:

1. Download OBS --> It creates a virtual video camera
2. Download (pip install) pyvirtualcam (allowes you to operate with the OBS cam)
3. you can now send pictures to the cam using the module:

```
cam = pyvirtualcam.Camera(width=int(capture.get(3)), height=int(capture.get(4)), fps=30)
cam.send(<Photo>)
```

Also make if you use a while loop to put this code in the end:

```
cam.sleep_until_next_frame()
```